# How free memory after using `Ext.window.Window` class instance?

Tags: javascript, extjs, destroy, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I'm using [Extjs-6](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0) for developing my application. I have most than 20 controller in my application. In all of these controllers, some times, these controllers show a [`Ext.window.Window`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.window.Window) class instance and then user close this window(In other hands, All controller can show a popup).
Is it true that I use `destroy` function for closing the `window`? Is this frees memory? This way don't occur leakage memory? In a sentence, **What's the best wa**y?

Comment: autoDestoy (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-cfg-autoDestroy) is set to true for containers. It is not necessary to destroy anything manually. Maybe the App inspector plugin (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/app-inspector-for-sencha/pbeapidedgdpniokbedbfbaacglkceae) for Chrome will help you to show you which components still exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When [`close`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-method-close) is called (whether as the result of user click, or programmatically), [`destroy`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-method-destroy) is called behind the scenes, and everything in regards to preventing memory leaks is cared of for you by the framework. So, unless there are relevant bugs, you don't need to worry about that at all.

It is still a good practice, though, to get rid of any references to objects that no longer exist / in use. So, if you somewhere created a reference to you window like this:

```
this.win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window'....
```

it will be a good idea to delete it when the window is closed:

```
delete this.win;
```

Comment: If you use a global event bus for communicating across your app, like with say web sockets, make sure you disconnect these handlers.